# JavaFX ComboBox: difference between methods of adding listeners/event handlers

Tags: java, combobox, javafx, javafx-8

I am using the ComboBox and ChoiceBox controls, and have been trying to figure out the difference between the methods of executing an action when an item is selected. What is the difference between the following?

```
ComboBox<String> comboBox = 
  new ComboBox(
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(
      "Hi", 
      "Hello", 
      "Test");

comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
  (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println(newValue));

comboBox.valueProperty().addListener(
  (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println(newValue));

comboBox.setOnAction(
  event -> System.out.println(comboBox.getValue()));
```

A ChoiceBox doesn't have the onAction property, but it does have the others, both which appear to do the same thing. Which is recommended and what is the difference?

I would also like to know whether it is better to set the StringConverter or the CellFactory for a ComboBox; a ChoiceBox necessitates the usage of StringConverter, but I've been using the `setCellFactory(Callback<ListView<T>, ListCell<T>>)` method for my ComboBoxes (it's necessary for at least one, since the internal labels have ImageViews set as the graphic).

One last thing – I have a number of 'refresh' methods in my application which are run on the execution of an action (for instance, the selection of an item from the ComboBox or ChoiceBox). Would it be better to use binding instead? I'm not quite sure if this is possible, since my code isn't using wrapped values (properties/ObservableValue).

I've tried searching for the answers to these questions, but I haven't quite found it yet.

Answer (score 1):

OnAction handlers deal with events: it means you can for instance stop the propagation of the event by calling consume(). Other listeners based on this event won't be called (depends if it is an EventHandler or an EventFilter, see DOM 3 Event Model with differences between capture and bubbling phases).

You simply can't do that easily with listeners based on property.

CellFactory or StringConverter? They don't behave the same, so you should decide what's best for you. If you don't touch the components, maybe it is best to just use a converter? Or maybe you want to use only one technique in your project for easier evolutions and maintenance? You decide.

Binding or manual refresh? Depends on the case. Do you want a synchronous update all the time or just "on-demand"? Binding is great, but it can become difficult to add behaviour between two updates, and sometimes it is very difficult to debug. "Simplicity over cleverness" should apply.

Comment: That answered most of my questions. However, I'm still not sure of the functional difference between calling `comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()` and `comboBox.valueProperty()`, especially in a non-editable ComboBox. It seems to mostly do the same thing.

Comment: The selection model is also supported by the TreeView widget. There may be a reason to interface to the selection because you can then use the same code for a combo box or a tree view. At the same time, the tree view would actually support a selection with multiple items (when you use getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE)), so not sure how practical that is.